# Why I receive "This API call could not be completed due to resource limits"

Tags: facebook

> Facebook.Utility.FacebookException:
>   This API call could not be completed
>   due to resource limits

Why I receive this  when calling _facebookAPI.Events.GetMembers(eid); Is there any workaround?

My event has 5000+ users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to get the entire list if it's greater than 5k for performance reasons. Depending on what you want to do with this data, you can instead ask a more limited question of "is uid X attending event Y".

Comment: can you please specify how to do this query?

Answer (score 1):

I recently started getting this from some FQL queries.  For FQL at the least, it appears to be entirely unrelated to response size - I'm able to return much, much more than 5k worth of data.

What *did* break the limit was including mutual_friend_count in my user query.  500 users-worth would sometimes break the limit, 1000 would most of the time, while I can pull in several thousand if I remove that one column (even if I add 10 more).

For daaku's "is uid x attending event y", you can do this in FQL:

```
select eid, uid, rsvp_status from event_member where eid = <event id> and uid = <user id>
```

Or in the Graph API (there are a few other lists on events):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<event id>/attending
```

Both of those methods allow limit / offset, which will get past any such limits that may still occur:

```
select eid, uid, rsvp_status from event_member where eid = <event id> and uid = <user id> limit X offset Y
-- or --
https://graph.facebook.com/<event id>/attending?limit=X&offset=Y
```

And, though I realize this is quite a bit later than when the question was posted: you should be migrating away from the REST API and towards FQL or the Graph API, both of which are far, *far* more capable than the REST API.